# Spark: Compare the similarity

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

```
index |  Distribution |
+-----+--------------------+
|    0|  [1, 2, 0 ]   |
|    1|  [1, 5, 0 ]   |
|    2|  [1, 9, 0 ]   |
...
```

and a list:

```
a = [1, 0, 0]
```

Now I want a new column in this data frame which shows the distance between list **a** and elements in the **Distribution** column:

```
index |  Distribution | distan |
+-----+------------------------+
|    0|  [1, 2, 0 ]   |    2   |
|    1|  [1, 5, 0 ]   |    5   |
|    2|  [1, 9, 0 ]   |    9   |
...
```

I tried to use

```
numpy.linalg.norm()
```

But I dont know how to loop it into this dataframe.

May I ask how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `udf`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean as euclidean_
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, [1, 2, 0]), (1, [1, 5, 0]), (2, [1, 9, 0])],
    ["index", "distribution"])

euclidean = lambda x: udf(lambda y: euclidean_(x, y).tolist(), "double")

df.withColumn("dis", euclidean(a)("Distribution"))

## +-----+------------+---+
## |index|distribution|dis|
## +-----+------------+---+
## |    0|   [1, 2, 0]|2.0|
## |    1|   [1, 5, 0]|5.0|
## |    2|   [1, 9, 0]|9.0|
## +-----+------------+---+
```